# Passing context for a radio group in a fragment instead of activity?

Tags: android-studio, android-fragments, radio-group

I'm trying to use a RadioGroup widget inside a fragment instead of an activity. I'm getting an error on the following line of code:

```
RadioButton button = new RadioButton(this);
```

I'm not sure what to pass instead of 'this'

I believe the problem is either in the snippet above or here:

```
RadioGroup group = (RadioGroup) getView().findViewById(R.id.radioGroup);
```

Full code:

```
public class fragment1 extends Fragment {

private Button btnNextFrag;

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment1_layout, container, false);

    createRadioButtons();
    return view;
}

private void createRadioButtons() {
    RadioGroup group = (RadioGroup) getView().findViewById(R.id.radioGroup);

    String[] questions1 = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.question_1_answers);
    for (int i=0;i<questions1.length;i++){
        String question = questions1[i];

        RadioButton button = new RadioButton(this);
        button.setText(question);
        group.addView(button);
    }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The constructor requires context so use `getActivity()` instead of `this`. You can also use `getContext()`.

Comment: I tried this fist, but although I don't get errors, my app crashes when trying to load the fragment...

Comment: You should post the stack trace from the logcat.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class fragment1 extends Fragment {

private Button btnNextFrag;

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment1_layout, container, false);
    createRadioButton(view);
    return view;

}

private void createRadioButton(View view) {
    RadioGroup group = (RadioGroup)view.findViewById(R.id.radioGroup);

    String[] questions1 = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.question_1_answers);
    for (int i=0;i<questions1.length;i++){
        String question = questions1[i];
        RadioButton button = new RadioButton(getActivity());
        button.setText(question);
        group.addView(button);
    }
}


}
```